# The Hofstadter butterfly

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

How The Hofstadter butterfly consistent with Landau levels? As I understand the Landau levels are obtained for free electrons and if we turn on the periodic crystal field we get butterfly. But it's difficult to understand  how the Hofstadter butterfly transforms  to Landau levels if the crystal field turn off?

Comment: Look at the top of the butterfly. You will see multiple bands of energy levels that then get more complicated toward the middle of the butterfly. These bands are the remnants of the Landau Levels.